# What method an active record object gets called when Rails tries to figure out the route for it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table in my database called `markets`
I have an active record class that corresponds to it called (of all things) Market.

In my Haml file I've got something like this

```
%h3=link_to market.name, market
```

Everything is perfect...

But I when I extend the class (inherit) with this

```
class EbayMarket < Market
end
```

Now my `link_to` is looking for the `ebay_market` path. which I don't have, nore do I want to create one.  I plan on overriding the class for things other than display, so my GUI stays the same, how I send data to that market (to ebay in this case) is different for each market type (Google, eBay, shopping, Magneto, etc.).

What I'd like to do is override the method that is called on the link_to that changes the object to a path. Could someone please tell me either what method gets called, or how to find it.

Comment: Have you tried using a named route? `= link_to market.name, market_path(market)`. Unless your **EbayMarket** and **Market** models share the same database table I would avoid this.

Comment: they are the same table.  In fact there would never be an instance of a Market.  It is always inherited.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid changing the views, because I am not always the one who cuts their code, and I don't want someone to put link_to ... market and have it blow up on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. I wanted to be able to add the routs for an inherited class, with as little code as possible.  I didn't want to got into the routs file, because I wanted to limit the amount of files that get touched when a new developer comes on and creates a class for a new market.

I managed to create a rout dynamically by adding the following to my base class.
Now the creator of the inherited classes has to do "nothing".  Not one line of code needs to be added to allow the inherited class to use the same controller as the super.

```
def self.add_rout()
    _table_name = self.table_name;
    _my_name = self.to_s.underscore; 
    _routes = Rails.application.routes
    _routes.disable_clear_and_finalize = true
    _routes.clear!
    Rails.application.routes_reloader.paths.each{ |path| load(path) }
    _routes.draw {resources _table_name, :as => _my_name    }
    ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) { _routes.finalize! }
  ensure
    _routes.disable_clear_and_finalize = false
  end
  add_rout();
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a generic "markets" controller, you'll need to setup an additional resource for each inherited model while [specifying the controller to use](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use). Using **EbayMarket** as an example, you would add the following line to your **routes.rb** file:

```
resource :ebay_markets, :controller => "markets"
```

If you wish to avoid some duplication, see [routing concerns](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns).

Comment: I am most surprised there is not a method in the class that figures out the resoures.

Comment: @baash05 If code could write itself we wouldn't need programmers.

Comment: I wasn't expecting a bit of code that would write itself.  I was expecting that at some point link_to "",market would result in a call to a method in the market object/class.  How does it know what type of object market is?  Reflection I'd assume.  But that must be a call in the object?  No